# Split columns into rows based on data type

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have a table like this

```
 parent_id       col1        col2       col3
     101          John         1       9/12/2009 4:33:22 PM
     102          Fid          2       2/10/2005 12:54:01 PM
     103          Smith        3       6/4/2005 10:10:11 PM
```

col1 is char
col2 is int
col1 is timestamp

And would like to create a second table based on the first table with sample output like below

```
 parent_id   ColName       Charvalue    IntValue  TimeValue
     101     Col1            John         null      null
     101     Col1            Fid          null      null       
     101     Col1            Smith        null      null              
     102     Col2            null          1        null       
     102     Col2            null          2        null       
     102     Col2            null          3        null       
     103     Col3            null         null      9/12/2009 4:33:22 PM
     103     Col3            null         null      2/10/2005 12:54:01 PM
     103     Col3            null         null      6/4/2005 10:10:11 PM
```

Should I use unpivot to achieve in MS SQL Server?

Comment: based on the data type of which column ? Please explain how do you get from the top to the bottom table ?

Comment: @Squirrel  col1 is char type, col2 is int, ad col3 is timestamp. Records must be split into multiple rows with every new row having the values for one of the data types and remaining columns as null

Comment: @Stu I would like to split the rows according to the data types and create a new table with the sample output data given above

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`, this only requires a single scan of the base table so is very efficient

```sql
SELECT
  t.parentid,
  v.ColName,
  v.Charvalue,
  v.IntValue,
  v.TimeValue
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('col1', t.col1, NULL, NULL),
    ('col2', NULL, t.col2, NULL),
    ('col3', NULL, NULL, t.col3)
) v(ColName, Charvalue, IntValue, TimeValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` instead of `unpivot`

```
SELECT 101 parent_id ,col1,NULL col2,NULL col3 
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 102,NULL,col2 ,NULL  
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 103,NULL ,NULL,col3
FROM T
```

Comment: It works; but how to do it for a huge dataset without hardcoding the ParentID values. Also, I need to add a new column and populate the values as per the sample output